# Android:how to view dynamic Table layout in a custom dialog

Tags: android, customdialog

I am creating and android application that consists of the table layout created dynamically here i want to display that table layout in a custom dialog.I had call the generated table layout which was present in the another activity inside the dialog activity  but it was showing empty dialog with the dialog name can any one tell me where i did the mistake
Here my dynamic table layout generation activity:

```
EDIT:------------
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("MANUAL MODE : AFTER FUSE CONNECTION");
        menu.add(1, v.getId(), 0, "TEST  ");
        menu.add(1, v.getId(), 0, "SELECT ALL  ");
        menu.add(1, v.getId(), 0, "DESELECT ALL  ");
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getTitle()=="TEST  ")
        {
    progresDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());

                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                    progresDialog.setTitle("MANUAL MODE : TESTING ");

                    View dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progressdialog, null);
                    progresDialog.setContentView(dialogview);
                    table_dialog = (TableLayout)dialogview.findViewById(R.id.table_layout_1);

                    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {

                        TableRow row = new TableRow(getActivity());
                        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                        for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {

                            TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
                            tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
                            tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                            tv.setText("R " + i + ", C" + j);

                            row.addView(tv);

                        }

                        table_dialog.addView(row);

                    }

                    progresDialog.show();

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create table layout dynamically inside thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140323/how-to-create-table-layout-dynamically-inside-thread)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have called layout in your dialog but you are creating the layout via java code. You need to do below things given:

1.Change it to AlertDialog or more appropriate if you create DialogFragment.
2.Instead of using

```
dialog.setContentView(layout id);
```

use this:

```
dialog.setContentView(view object);
```

And how to use this method? Let me show you a sample example

```
LayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOU_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_progressdialogactivity, null);
```

Now recognize your table layout here:

```
 table_layout = (TableLayout) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tl_1);
```

And then add your for loop here;

Comment: Dude is layout inflater was the correct in the above because it was showing me an error and i am creating a dialog inside fragment @Khushal Chouhan

Comment: K dude  i am working on it can u please wait for some time @Kushal Chouhan

Comment: Yes I am available till 6.30

Comment: Dude not working dude again showing empty dialog with dialog name only i'll edit my post can you check it out please @Kushal Chouhan

Comment: I told you to use AlertDialog

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82074/discussion-between-bujjideepu-and-khushal-chouhan).